Probability theory - conditional expectation
Give an example of two random variables $X, Y$ such that $E[X|Y] = Y$ but $P(X = Y) = 0$.
I noticed that by letting $Z=X-Y$ it's equivilant to find $Z$ such that $E[Z|Y]=0$ and $P(Z=0)=0$, but I can't seem to find any example for that and would like for help/hint.

Let $Y$ be whatever you like and let $X=Y+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon =\pm 1$ with equal probability, independent of $Y$.
